How to make an image to fullfill the <v-main> window
its the first time for me to use vuetify to create my own website. the question is: i want to place an image to my homepage and it has to full fill the <v-main> window.i have no idea how to do it.
Does anyone know the key to solve this problem?
the structure of my home page is simple :
  <v-app>

    <v-navigation-drawer expand-on-hover rail>...</v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-main class="d-flex flex-column">
      <v-container class="h-100 bg-grey-lighten-4" width="100vw">
        <v-img
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/parallax/material.jpg"
          height="100%"
          cover
        ></v-img>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>

    <v-footer class="d-flex flex-column" app>... </v-footer>

  </v-app>

but the result is not what i expected:
enter image description here
the image didn't fill the width of the remaining  area.

Constraining content to not stretch the full viewport is one of the reasons you use v-container. Even if you didn't know this, the proper way to figure out why anything looks the way it does is to use your browser's dev tools to inspect the DOM, which in this case will reveal that v-container has a max-width property preventing the full screen width. You could add your own CSS to override this property, or find in Vuetify's API that the prop fluid accomplishes the same thing

fluid 
Removes viewport maximum-width size breakpoints.

<v-container fluid class="h-100 bg-grey-lighten-4">

